# Install Locally using dnf in Fedora without using internet connection

Tags: rpm, dnf

I am trying to locally install an `rpm` package without using the internet. I tried the following:

```
sudo rpm -u kernel-devel-4.2.7-200.fc22.x86_64.rpm
```

and I got:

```
error: kernel-devel-4.2.7-200.fc22.x86_64.rpm: hdr blob(2060952): BAD, read returned 0
error: kernel-devel-4.2.7-200.fc22.x86_64.rpm cannot be installed
```

I also tried:

```
sudo dnf --disablerepo='*' install kernel-devel-4.2.7-200.fc22.x86_64.rpm
```

and it still seems to be using the internet, so I can't figure out if it works or not since the internet connection is really slow.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: `sudo dnf install /path/to/package.rpm`

Comment: @ILMostro_7 Thanks, but it's still using the internet.

Comment: @ILMostro_7 actually sorry, it works now. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds good.  In that case, please accept the answer as the correct solution.

Answer (score 45):

`sudo dnf install /path/to/package.rpm` will act on the package in the given path.

Comment: When trying this on a LIVE cd, I have to add `--disablerepo=*`

Comment: @Andy, I'm not sure if that's something that has changed with recent versions of `dnf`, but I don't see why you wouldn't be able to install the package locally by explicitly providing the full path to the `rpm` file as suggested in the answer.

Comment: I found out that in the end, you are right. What was happening for me, is that I was trying to install 10 RPMs, but I was accidentally missing one dependency. I had never run a dnf command online, so my yum cache was empty. Without --disablerepo, all I got was an error message failing to update the "Updates" repo. So I had no idea what the error was, but with the --disablerepo, I got a nice clear message that I was missing an package.

Comment: @Andy please accept the answer if it's correct.

Comment: I've also seen `sudo dnf localinstall <package>` used.  Any difference in behavior?

Comment: I'll answer my own comment, `localinstall` is a deprecated alias for `install` : https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html

Comment: @ILMostro_7, in my case the system does not have access to the repositories over the network and the installation hangs when updating the metadata.
So `--disablerepo=*` skips updating the metadata and starts installing the local package right away.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo dnf localinstall kernel-devel-4.2.7-200.fc22.x86_64.rpm
```

This worked for me!